# Calculate a growth ratio week over week in SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

I have a SQL Server table contains [date], [category], [year], [week], [Month], [Volume Received].

Here's the query I wrote for getting weekly sum[Volume] per category for last 4 years.

```
    SELECT Year([Date]) AS [D_Year]
       , [Week] AS [Week of Year]
       , SUM([Volume Received])AS [Received]
       , [Category]
  FROM [t1]
  WHERE YEAR(Date) in ('2016', '2017', '2018','2019')

  GROUP BY Year([Date]), [Week], [Category]
```

It give me this table:

```
 > year   week      received     category  
 > 2016     1         51123         A 
 > 2016     2         41123         A 
 > 2016     3         21123         B 
 > 2016     1         5113          D 
 >  ...
 > 2017     18         1113         A
 >  ...
 > 2019     1         11134         C
```

**I'm looking for one SQL Statement that will give me average growth ratio by week per category.**

I've done it manually in EXCEL but thats not updating when I refresh my connection to SQL Server.

Final output I want is something like this:

```
> week      ratio      category  
> 1         -0.05         A 
> 1          0.15         B 
> 1          0.02         C 
> 1         -0.25         D
> 2          0.25         A 
> 2         -0.15         B 
> 2          0.02         C 
> 2         -0.25         D
```

Comment: That final view is just example by what I want to see. Form my code and the table I pull, there should be 52 wks data per year..... I am not sure how to make it in SQL Statement that's the main point I am asking for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your existing query and use window function `LAG()` to get the previous value of `[Received]`:

```
SELECT
    [D_Year],
    [Week of Year],
    (
        [Received] 
        - LAG([Received]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Category] ORDER BY [D_Year], [Week of Year])
    ) / [Received] [Ratio]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Year([Date]) AS [D_Year],
        [Week] AS [Week of Year]
        SUM([Volume Received]) AS [Received],
        [Category]
    FROM [t1]
    WHERE YEAR(Date) IN (2016, 2017, 2018, 2019)
    GROUP BY 
        Year([Date]), 
        [Week], 
        [Category]
) t
```

Comment: Hi I try it, won't let me, showing invalid column name of [Received]. Then I change it to SUM([Volume Received]), still not works too.

Comment: @nonslearn: I had a typo in the inner query (missing space before the  `AS` keyword), that I just fixed. Apart from that it cannot see other issues. Is the updated query working for you?

Comment: It looks like the LAG function not work for me, I am using SQL Server 2016, is that adaptable for LAG function?

Comment: @nonslearn: yes, `LAG()` is available in SQL Server 2016. I fixed another typo (superfluous parenthese in the ratio computation), how is it working now?

Comment: It works! Thank you, I will go ahead and do more search about LAG function, it's way more better than I am manually calculating in EXCEL.